# Цикл for - почему такой результат?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Почему `0, 4, 9`, а не `0, 4, 10`. Ведь сначала `i+j = 4`, потом `6`. Почему в итоге `5`?

```
for ($i = 0, $j = 2; $i < 11; $i++, $j++,  $i = $i + $j) {
   echo i;
}
```

Comment: `Ведь сначала i+j = 4, потом 6` - как считал? `Почему в итоге 5?` - откуда вообще 5?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У меня выводит в браузере `0, 4, 9`. Считал `0++ и 2++ = 4`, следующий цикл `1++ и 3++ = 6`. В итоге `4 + 6 = 10, а не 9`.
Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. цикл `$i = 0`, `$j = 2`

   после цикла:

   - `$i++` = 0 + 1 = 1
   - `$j++` = 2 + 1 = 3
   - `$i = $i + $j` = 1 + 3 = 4
2. цикл `$i = 4`, `$j = 3`

   после цикла:

   - `$i++` = 4 + 1 = 5
   - `$j++` = 3 + 1 = 4
   - `$i = $i + $j` = 5 + 4 = 9
3. цикл `$i = 9`, `$j = 4`

   после цикла: 
   уже не имеет значения что там

Comment: Понял логику, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
 for ($i = 0, $j = 2; $i < 11; $i++, $j++, $i = $i + $j ) {
    echo '$i='. $i . ' <br>';
    echo '$j='. $j. ' <br> ';
    echo '<hr>';
 }

 /**
 Итерация 1

  *) $i = 0;
  *) $j = 2;
  *) Условие $i(0) < 11 соблюдено? да > продолжаем   
  *) Печатаем $i = 0;
  *) Печатаем $j = 2;


 Итерация 2
  *) $i++ ; $i = 0 + 1 = 1; 
  *) $j++; $j = 2 + 1 = 3;
  *) $i = $i + $j; $i = 3 + 1 = 4;

  *) Условие $i(4) < 11 соблюдено? да > продолжаем   
  *) Печатаем $i = 4;
  *) Печатаем $j = 3;

 Итерация 3 
  *) $j++; $j = 3 + 1 = 4;
  *) $i++ ; $i = 4 + 1 = 5;
  *) $i = $i + $j; $i = 5 + 4 = 9;
  *) Условие $i(9) < 11 соблюдено? да > продолжаем   
  *) Печатаем $i = 9;
  *) Печатаем $j = 4;
**/
```